# Android HttpUrlConnection Timeout but before server Response

Tags: android, http, tomcat

i have a problem that confuse me , please help me. i have a problem when using http client connecting to url where the problem is like this. 
1. app send request to url at time 10:00:00
2. after 15 second app timeout but in server log the request is not received yet.
3. after a while from app timeout like at 10:00:30  the server showing log from app reqest.

because of this problem there is double transaction because app keep trying sending http request, can anyone explain this problem this and is there any ways to prevent double sending transaction ??

for server i am using tomcat 7 and the android app sending data from background every 5 minute.

please help me, thank's in advance

Comment: Added Internet permission in android manifest.xml?

Answer (score 0):

> there is double transaction because app keep trying sending http request, can anyone explain this problem this and is there any ways to prevent double sending transaction ??

Stop the application from trying to resend, or else make the transaction [idempotent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence#Computer_science_meaning) so that sending it again does no harm.